# May xs:documentation contain HTML tags?

Tags: xsd

My goal is to make a programmer's manual to my web-service. There are many tools that generate manuals directly from XSD source, and these tools use `<xs:documentation>` intensively.

So I'm adding a much as possible `<xs:documentation>` tags to my XSD.

Question: may `<xs:documentation>` contain HTML code, e.g. hyperlinks? Formally, it MAY while HTML contain is valid XML. But will this content be supported by third-party tools like manual generators mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

May xs:documentation contain XHTML?  Yes, it may.  That is, doing so is allowed by the schema for schema documents.

Will tools do something useful with it?  Some do (at least [the stylesheet I wrote for displaying XSD schema documents in the browser](http://www.w3.org/XML/2004/xml-schema-test-suite/xsd.xsl) does), others probably not.  If the tools you want to use don't deal well with XHTML in the xs:documentation element, raise the issue with the developers or vendors.

Answer (score 1):

[xs3p](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xs3p/) supports HTML tags within documentation elements. HTML content must be well-formed XML, HTML tags should have `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace declared:

```
<xs:element ...>
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      Here is 
      <code xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">source code<code> 
      example
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```